# Ruby Basic Collision Detection using text

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a simple text-based ruby game that is basically a maze. I've already planned where to put the "walls" in the area I've built. The only problem is that whenever I try to check to see if the "player" or an entity collides, it doesn't. It just goes on as if there weren't any walls put up.
Here's the code:

```
#Maze Preset 1 Testing
wallpos = [5,1],[1,2],[3,2],[4,2],[2,4],[3,4],[5,4],[3,5]
puts wallpos
x = gets
y = gets
pos = Array[x,y]
if pos == wallpos
    puts ""
    puts "Intersect"
else
    puts ""
    puts "Nope."
end
```

Notes: I placed a puts wallpos and puts pos so I could see if the values I got are correct.

Comment: While you *can* assign an array like `wallpos = [5,1],[1,2],[3,2],[4,2],[2,4],[3,4],[5,4],[3,5]`, don't. Instead, wrap the elements in a containing set of brackets: `wallpos = [[5,1],[1,2],[3,2],[4,2],[2,4],[3,4],[5,4],[3,5]]`. This is idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Petr said, you need to process your input correctly:

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
y = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Also, you are using the equality operator (`==`) incorrectly.  A single coordinate pair cannot ever be equal to an array of coordinates.  Instead, you should use [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) to check if the coordinates are found in the array.  The code would look like this:

```
if wallpos.include?(pos)
```

By the way, the `p` method is great for debugging.  If you are not sure of a value in your program (say, foo) you can print it out by adding:

```
p foo
```

which is short for

```
puts foo.inspect
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple things about using `gets`:

1. It includes a `"\n"` character after the user's input. As @7stud pointed out in his comment, it is the *input record separator*.
2. It returns a string.

To fix your issue, use it like this:

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
y = gets.chomp.to_i
```

[`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) strips the newline character from the end of the string.

Also, regarding `pos == wallpos`: You are comparing that your position is equal to the entire `wallpos` array. Change it to `wallpos.include?(pos)`.

Comment: *A couple things about using gets: It most likely appends a \n character to the end of the string.* -- `gets()` doesn't append anything to anything--it just reads what's there. `gets()` reads input up to and including the *input record separator*, then stops (that's probably what you meant).  The *input record separator* is a ruby global variable, which is set to `\n` (newline) by default.  However, you can set the input record separator to anything you want, e.g. the string `"a"`, in which case gets() will read up to and including the first `"a"` in the input.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did not know that it is a global variable.